# Android: Button at the corner of maps

Tags: android, button, maps

I wanted to create a button in my Android maps at the top right corner(has to stay there all the time, even if I move in the map). when tapped the map should go to satellite view, when tapped again it should come back to street view.

I have the code for street view and map view, I just want to know how to create a button that stays always at the top right corner.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Yashwanth. But I am a bit confused. I am new to Android. can you please elaborate and tell me where to write this code? Should I do it in Manifest file or main.xml file ? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout>
<Button
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
// place your other map or street view here.

</RelativeLayout>
```

use this layout.